# AWS WAF Update IP set Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, rundeck, web-application-firewall

I am trying to automate the process of updating IPs to help engineers whitelist IPs on AWS WAF IP set. `aws waf-regional update-ip-set` returns a `ChangeToken` which has to be used in the next run of `update-ip-set` command.

This automation I am trying to achieve is through Rundeck job (community edition). Ideally engineers will not have access to the output of previous job to retrieve `ChangeToken`. What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the step output using the "Mask Log Output by Regex" output filter.

Take a look at the following job definition example, the first step is just a simulation of getting the token, but it's hidden by the filter.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: fcf8cf5d-697c-42a1-affb-9cda02183fdd
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TokenWorkflow
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "abc123"
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'false'
            name: mytoken
            regex: s*([^\s]+?)\s*
          type: key-value-data
        - config:
            maskOnlyValue: 'false'
            regex: .*
            replacement: '[SECURE]'
          type: mask-log-output-regex
    - exec: echo ${data.mytoken}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: fcf8cf5d-697c-42a1-affb-9cda02183fdd
```

The second step uses that token (to show the [data passing](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/passing-variables.html#passing-data-between-steps) the steps print the data value generated in the first step, of course in your case the token is used by another command).

***Update (passing the data value to another job)***

Just use the [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step) and put the data variable name on the remote job option as an argument.

Check the following example:

The first job generates the token (or gets it from your service, hiding the result like in the first example). Then, it calls another job that "receives" that data in an option (Job Reference Step > Arguments) using this format:

```
-token ${data.mytoken}
```

Where `-token` is the target job option name, and `${data.mytoken}` is the current data variable name.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: fcf8cf5d-697c-42a1-affb-9cda02183fdd
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TokenWorkflow
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "abc123"
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'false'
            name: mytoken
            regex: s*([^\s]+?)\s*
          type: key-value-data
        - config:
            maskOnlyValue: 'false'
            regex: .*
            replacement: '[SECURE]'
          type: mask-log-output-regex
    - jobref:
        args: -token ${data.mytoken}
        group: ''
        name: ChangeRules
        nodeStep: 'true'
        uuid: b6975bbf-d6d0-411e-98a6-8ecb4c3f7431
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: fcf8cf5d-697c-42a1-affb-9cda02183fdd
```

This is the job that receive the token and do something, the example show the token but the idea is to use internally to do some action (like the first example).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: b6975bbf-d6d0-411e-98a6-8ecb4c3f7431
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ChangeRules
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: token
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo ${option.token}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: b6975bbf-d6d0-411e-98a6-8ecb4c3f7431
```

Comment: Thank you for this. For the second part, I want to pass the data from one job to another and not the next step in the same job. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can use the Job Reference Step and pass the data variable name to a remote job option (and use it). I updated my answer with a fully reproducible example to see how works.

Comment: My apologies if I didn't address the terms properly. I want to use the `--change-token` from one execution of Job A in another execution of Job A itself.
When I run Job A the first time, I receive a `--change-token`, this should be saved to a variable and when the next execution runs, it should have this updated token to update the WAF rule.